# intent.putExtra() Error on OS 4.0 - how to fix that?

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm trying to start an activity through a button, which contains putExtra.But the app stops working on the button, I tried to disable **android:hardwareAccelerated = "false"** in Manifest, but this does not work on android 4.0, could anyone help me?

**But the error is displayed**

`E/dalvikvm: VM aborting
 A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 14318`

Code in **MainActivity**:

```
  public void Button (View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Site.class);
    intent.putExtra("url", "https://example.com/");
    startActivity(intent); }
```

**Site.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;


public class Site extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = Site.class.getSimpleName();


    protected WebView mainWebView;
    private Context mContext;
    private WebView mWebviewPop;
    private FrameLayout mContainer;


    private String url = "http://example.com";// 


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_blog);

        mContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mContext = this.getApplicationContext();

        clearCookies(this);

        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);


        mainWebView = getWebView(mContext);


        mainWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyCustomChromeClient());

        mainWebView.loadUrl(url);

        mContainer.addView(mainWebView);


    }



    WebView getWebView(Context context) {
        WebView wv = new WebView(context);
        wv.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        wv.clearCache(true);


        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(wv, true);
        }


        return wv;
    }


    private class MyCustomChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
                                      boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
            mWebviewPop = getWebView(mContext);
            mWebviewPop.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    String host = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
                    Log.d(TAG, "host=" + host);
                    if (host.contains("facebook.com")) {
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        return true;
                    }

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            mWebviewPop.setWebChromeClient(new MyCustomChromeClient());

            mContainer.addView(mWebviewPop);

            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(mWebviewPop);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {

            Log.d("onCloseWindow", "called");

            mWebviewPop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mContainer.removeView(mWebviewPop);
            mWebviewPop = null;

        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void clearCookies(Context context) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Using clearCookies code for API >=" + String.valueOf(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1));
            CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
            CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Using clearCookies code for API <" + String.valueOf(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1));
            CookieSyncManager cookieSyncMngr = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
            cookieSyncMngr.startSync();
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
            cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
            cookieSyncMngr.stopSync();
            cookieSyncMngr.sync();
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_site:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Site.class is declared in your manifest.xml?

Comment: @statosdotcom Yes, and the **<uses-permission android: name = "android.permission.INTERNET"/>** permission too.

Comment: I don't think this can make any difference but in my code I use only the word **this** to refer to actual class, not the entire class name followed by **this**. I mean, using your code, "my intent" would be something like: **Intent intent = new Intent(this, Site.class);** as the button code. Maybe it worth a try.

Comment: @statosdotcom You are correct that will have zero effect. `MainActivity.this` and `this` are the same.  Use cases for class reference followed by `.this` are used for anonymous classes (closures), or inner classes where you want to reference the outer class in a explicit fashion i.e. have same named variables in both classes.

Comment: @MarkKeen many thanks. Best.

Comment: @statosdotcom I tried, and it did not work. But thanks for the help.

Comment: Where (or what) is **activity_blog.xml**?

Comment: @statosdotcom I changed to activity_site, and it does not work too :(      Works on Android 7.0, but not on 4.0.

Comment: Changing to **activity_site** your app raised another error? If so, where?

Comment: The error remains **E / dalvikvm: VM aborting**  **A / libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) to 0xdeadd00d (code = 1), thread 30761** in logcat.

Comment: @statosdotcom   Worked on api 16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code (**Site.java**), change

```
activity_blog.xml
```

To

```
activity_site.xml
```

Which is the name of your layout file. Then comment out the following line:

```
mainWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyCustomChromeClient());
```

Either in your **Site.java**, cause this was raising errors here in my test. Later you decide what you want to do with the previous code regarded to it. With this you have your project running on apis >= 14. Best luck.